# Why is the link bigger than the span inside?

Tags: html, css

I´m experimenting a bit with css sprites and have a small problem wich I tracked down to the following question.

I have this simple HTML and some styles applied - see the fiddle below.

```
<a href="#"><span class="fs"></span></a>
```

For the span I defined a fixed size of 16x16px - but the link area seems to be bigger (I assigned different colors). Why? I already tried to define a line-height of same size...

http://jsfiddle.net/tPemb/

I think I need a coffee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `float:left;`  in the `.fs`

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SbrcC/)

Answer (score 3):

just change the `display` to `block` like this...

```
.fs {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 56px;
    background: #ddd;
}​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPemb/1/)

`inline-block` causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box, read more in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display).

Comment: Thank you - both solutions worked for me. But I need the inline-block for placing the elements next to each other. Thank you for the link to the spec....